# Baking Guide Questions

Tags: node

I've previously setup masternodes and non-minting nodes and I want to setup a baking node. I have all the prerequisites ready to start a baking mainnet node, but I'm not comfortable on going ahead because I don't fully understand all the pieces of the tutorials when reading them top to bottom. So I was hoping I could walkthrough what I think is this most up to date guide and pose questions regarding some of the steps.

### Premise

I have a `TZ1` account with the necessary funds to start a baking operation. Let's assume for a second I've used TezBox to hold these funds. I also have a Ubuntu Server ready to go.

I will be following https://medium.com/@tezbaker.io/tezos-mainnet-setting-up-home-baking-4bf258a9fd30

### Node Setup

I get all the linux and build steps in that guide above. My questions start on the actual Tezos setup

`./tezos-node identity generate`

What identity is this? Are we generating an address (wallet?) for the baker? Since a baker has to hold 8.25% of the funds this is the address that I would assume the baker funds have to sent to. Unless there's a special type of delegate that is considered the baker and then you could sort that out with smart contracts without actually transfer of funds. Am I too off here?

`$ nohup ./tezos-node run --rpc-addr :8732 --log-output tezos.log &`

and

```
$ ./tezos-baker-004-Pt24m4xi run with local node ~/.tezos-node <baking_address>
$ ./tezos-accuser-004-Pt24m4xi run
$ ./tezos-endorser-004-Pt24m4xi run <baking_address>
```

Are these processes running in paralel, `tezos-node` and the other 3? I assume if the `tezos-node` is not running the others will obviouly not work properly. Correct?

What address is the `baking_address`? Is that the address generated in the `identity generate` step?

`Step: Generate a key with the alias my_account`

What is the purpose of these set of steps?

`Step: Create an originate contract for delegating`

This I think creates the address where others can delegate to. Correct?

---

By the end of the tutorial I still have these questions:
 - There were no funds transferred to the baking address. How is the baker associated with the funds required for baking, especially the bond?

I know it's quite a few questions, so thank you in an advance. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot of good questions here, but each question should be its own separate question. This will help others also instead of just helping your specific confusion. I would also try to encourage to search for relevant questions/answers that may answer these questions individually.

Comment: This question is too broad. You should try and break it up into some smaller questions each covering a single item

Comment: Please break this question into subquestions so that they can be addressed separately. This question will now be closed.